# How to create an empty IReadOnlyCollection

Tags: c#, .net, readonly-collection, multi-value-dictionary

I'm creating an extension method for [MultiValueDictionary](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2014/08/05/multidictionary-becomes-multivaluedictionary.aspx) to encapsulate frequent `ContainsKey` checks and I was wondering what was the best way to create an empty `IReadOnlyCollection`?.

What I've used so far is `new List<TValue>(0).AsReadOnly()` but there must be a better way, an equivilant to `IEnumerable`'s `Enumerable.Empty`

```
public static IReadOnlyCollection<TValue> GetValuesOrEmpty<TKey, TValue>(this MultiValueDictionary<TKey, TValue> multiValueDictionary, TKey key)
{            
    IReadOnlyCollection<TValue> values;
    return !multiValueDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out values) ? new List<TValue>(0).AsReadOnly() : values;
}
```

Comment: Not really, since `IReadOnlyCollection` is meant to be just a wrapper. You can consider returning an `IEnumerable<Value>`, or generally that does not have `Add` and `Remove` methods.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

EDIT: The new .Net 4.6 adds an API to get an empty array: [`Array.Empty<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn906179(v=vs.110).aspx) and arrays implement `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`. This also reduces allocations as it only creates an instance once:

```
IReadOnlyCollection<int> emptyReadOnlyCollection = Array.Empty<int>();
```

---

What I ended up doing is mimicking the implementation of [`Enumerable.Empty`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,4d026772cf3399f5,references) using `new TElement[0]`:

```
public static class ReadOnlyCollection
{
    public static IReadOnlyCollection<TResult> Empty<TResult>()
    {
        return EmptyReadOnlyCollection<TResult>.Instance;
    }

    private static class EmptyReadOnlyCollection<TElement>
    {
        static volatile TElement[] _instance;

        public static IReadOnlyCollection<TElement> Instance
        {
            get { return _instance ?? (_instance = new TElement[0]); }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
IReadOnlyCollection<int> emptyReadOnlyCollection = ReadOnlyCollection.Empty<int>();
```

Comment: Looks, good. But using `volatile` correctly is hard (here it is okay), but i'd like to stick to higher level apis and would pick a `private static Lazy<IReadOnlyCollection<TElement>> _EmptyCollection = new Lazy<IReadOnlyCollection<TElement>>(()=> new TElement[0]);` and within your Empty() method then take `return _EmptyCollection.Value;`

Answer (score 8):

`return new List<XElement>().AsReadOnly();`

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there's anything like `Enumerable.Empty` for read-only collections, but:

- `List<T>` already implements `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` so you can avoid one object allocation by not calling `AsReadOnly()` and simply casting the list instead. This is less "safe" in theory but hardly matters in practice.
- Alternatively, you could cache the returned ReadOnlyCollection to avoid any object allocation whatsoever (except for the cached object).

Comment: Went with a combination of both answers and used `return new TValue[0]`

Comment: @I3arnon: If you give your class a `private static IReadOnlyCollection<TValue> _EmptyCollection = new TValue[0]`, you only have to instantiate this empty array once instead whenever no value is available. Taking this a step further you could even pack this into a `Lazy<T>` which would create this empty array only when it is needed for the first time.

Comment: Nit: There is no need to even "cast" an expression of `List<T>` as `List<T>` (but not `IList<T>`) implements `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know there is no built in way(Interested to know if one). That said, you can use the following:

```
IReadOnlyCollection<TValue> readonlyCollection = new ReadOnlyCollection<TValue>(new TValue[] { });
```

Optionally you can cache the results as it is a `ReadOnlyCollection` over empty array, It will always be the same no matter how many instances you have.

Answer (score 2):

How's about this which has a similar syntax to Enumerable.Empty:

```
/// <summary>
/// Contains a method used to provide an empty, read-only collection.
/// </summary>
public static class ReadOnlyCollection
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns an empty, read-only collection that has the specified type argument.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">
    /// The type to assign to the type parameter of the returned generic read-only collection.
    /// </typeparam>
    /// <returns>
    /// An empty, read-only collection whose type argument is T.
    /// </returns>
    public static IReadOnlyCollection<T> Empty<T>()
    {
        return CachedValueProvider<T>.Value;
    }

    /// <summary/>
    static class CachedValueProvider<T>
    {
        /// <summary/>
        public static readonly IReadOnlyCollection<T> Value = new T[0];
    }
}
```

Used like this:

```
IReadOnlyCollection<int> empty = ReadOnlyCollection.Empty<int>();
```